# how can i execute the php file like " index.php?type=abc"

Tags: php

i created index.php file ,and i created form in abc.php,when i enter the url path  like "index.php/type=abc"  the form file i.e abc.php file has to be  executed.how can i do this.

my index.php file is

```
<?php include_once('header.php')?>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="min-width">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="tel:+254 0725117848" ><div class="button">CALL IPAIDABRIBE </div></a></li>
                <li><a href="new.php" ><div class="button">new</div></a></li>
                <li><a href="what.php" ><div class="button">what new</div></a></li>
                <li><a href="how.php"><div class="button">how</div></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include_once('footer.php')?>
```

abc.php code is

```
<form action=" "  method="post" id="contact-mail-page">
<div><div class="dealer-page">
       <h2>Interested in becoming a dealer, retailer or a part of our affiliate program for Picture Keeper? Please type in your
 information below and then click submit. You will be contacted within 48 hours.</p><br/>
 </h2>
        </div>
<div class="review">
<div class="form-item" id="edit-name-wrapper">
 <label for="edit-name">Bussiness Name <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label><br />
 <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="name" id="edit-name" size="30" value="" class="form-text required input">
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-name-wrapper">
 <label for="edit-name">Contact Name </label><br />
 <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="cname" id="edit-cname" size="30" value="" class="form-text required input">
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-name-wrapper">
 <label for="edit-add">Address <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label><br />
 <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="add" id="add" size="200" value="" class="form-text required input">
</div>
<div class="form-item" id="edit-name-wrapper">
 <label for="add1">Address1 <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label><br />
 <input type="text" maxlength="255" name="add1" id="add1" size="200" value="" class="form-text required input">
</div><br/>
<input class="dealer-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</div></form>
```

now here when i type the url path  like "index.php?type=abc" . this abc.php file has to be executed.how can i do this?
can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you want?If you want while the index.php?type=abc Url was intered, you Redirected to your Desired Page add this code above the index.php file.

```
<?php

$SafePages= array("abc", "login", "signin", "logout");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
if (in_array($_GET['type'],$SafePages))
{
header("location:".$_GET['type'].".php");
}
else
{
 header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');

    echo "<h1>404 Not Found</h1>";

    echo "The page that you have requested could not be found.";

    exit();

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["type"] = "abc") {
    include ("abc.php");
}
?>
```

That would go in your index.php file, just above the line that includes the footer.

Comment: i add the above code before <?php include_once('footer.php')?> this line, and enter the url path like index.php?type=abc  .this time i got the abc.php file o/p before the footer .but i dont want like this.

Comment: when i type the url index.php?type=abc ,that time only abc.php has to be executed.i mean when i enter the url like above ,that time the form in abc.php file has to displayed

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<!--HTML HERE-->
<?php
    if (in_array($_GET['type'], array('abc','more','etc'))){
        include ($_GET['type']. ".php");
    }
?>
<!-- MORE HTML HERE-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_GET)
   {

    if ($_GET["type"] = "abc") 
     {
       include ("abc.php");
     }
   }
?>
```

include this code in index.php